# in-memory and saved to file bitmaps are different for same byte[]

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I have a byte array. I then create a Bitmap object from it like this and display it in an ImageView:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
image.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
...
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
imgView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

I then create a file and store this byte array as an image

```
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
fOut.flush();
fOut.close();
```

When I open this file in Gallery, it looks different than the one in the ImageView. I tried to write the bytes directly to file, as opposed to the Bitmap, but then I was not able to open the image at all.

ImageView:

[image]

Gallery:

[image]

I thought that Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, endured no compression. What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I don't know if it matters, but the original bytes array comes from encrypting another byte array that came from an original picture. I loaded an image from disk, created a byte array, modified it, and then tried the above with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because you view your image with different background colors in your app and in Gallery. Since you use Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 and effectively feed it random data, some pixels will be transparent in the resulting image, and the color of the background will "shine through" when you view the image. If you make the background color of your app black, the image will probably look like it does in Gallery.